# Showing Individual Clock Times in Agenda Column View? (Org-Mode)

Tags: org-mode

When looking at the log view while in agenda-mode, tasks which have clock time associated with them show up as:

```
  plan:        9:15-10:48 Clocked:   (1:33) Task A
              10:00...... ----------------
  plan:       10:48-11:05 Clocked:   (0:17) Task B
  plan:       11:05-11:36 Clocked:   (0:31) Task B
```

Notice how `Task B` has two separate times associated with it: `0:17` and `0:31`. The `CLOCKSUM` for this task would be `0:48`.

**Question:** When viewing this information in column mode, how do you access the *individual* clock times for a task? I know that `CLOCKSUM` gets the sum of them, but I'm interested in the individual chunks of time not their sum. In this case, I would be interested in showing the `0:17` and `0:31` in the column view for `Task B`. Is this possible?